# How to fix this code, It's doing something weird and I don't understand why. Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

What the intention was in this code is to take from the `el-select` what the user has selected and add it into another array which will populate an `el-table`, only what has been selected.

Currently this code takes whats has been selected and adds the others to the array, got example if I have a, b, c to select from and I choose a, b and c get added to the array for the table instead of a.

This code is using things I'm not super familiar with that's why I can't seen to find where this is going all wrong.

```
addCourses() {
   const currentCourses = this.packageForm.package_courses.map((item) => item.course_id);
   const courses = this.courses.filter((item) => {
       return this.selectedCourses.indexOf(item.id) && currentCourses.indexOf(item.id) < 0
   });

   courses.forEach((course) => {
      this.packageForm.package_courses.push({
         course_id: course.id,
         course: course,
         price: 0
      });
  });
  this.selectedCourses = [];
},
```

The arrays used are being instanced in the script data in the vue

```
courses: [],
selectedCourses: [],
```

`package_courses` is in the data too but inside a form and is also just `package_courses: []`

These is the vue where the el-select and the el-table

```
<el-row>
    <el-col>
        <el-select v-model="selectedCourses"
            clearable
            filterable
            multiple
            placeholder="Select">

            <el-option
                v-for="item in courses"
                :key="item.id"
                :label="item.name"
                :value="item.id">
            </el-option>
        </el-select>
    </el-col>
    <el-col>
        <el-button @click="addCourses()" type="danger">
            Agregar Cursos
        </el-button>
    </el-col>
</el-row>
```

```
<el-table
    :data="packageForm.package_courses"
    show-summary
    :summary-method="getSummaries"
    border>

>all the other stuff in there

<el-table>
```

How do I fix it so it only adds what has been selected and not the rest, also when I click on the add button and haven't selected anything everything gets added, which I"m sure how I feel about that, It could be either way for me either add all or add none.

Comment: can you show a console.log of this.packageForm.package_courses at the end of addcorse ?

Comment: "This code is using things I'm not super familiar with". You don't need to be familiar with, seriously. Atleast just be familiar with `console.log`. Please log what's the content of `this.selectedCourses`.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
addCourses() {

   const courses = this.courses.filter((item) => {
   return this.selectedCourses.indexOf(item.id) > -1
   });

  courses.forEach((course) => {
  this.packageForm.package_courses.push({
     course_id: course.id,
     course: course,
     price: 0
  });
});
this.selectedCourses = [];
},
```